# Unable to zip a .txt file using pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-s3-client

I am trying to generate a file for a downstream consumer, for which we fetch data from an oracle table, and try to write a .txt.gz file into AWS S3.
The idea is as follows -

1. Generate multiple csv files, which get written into a single .txt file.
2. Zip this .txt file to produce a .txt.gz file to send to the consumer.

I am able to get through step 1, but not able to figure out step 2.

```
def execute_script(environment: str,logger, input_json_path: str = '', isdebug: bool = False):  
    print('Started')  
    config = ConfigurationManager(env=environment).oraclerds_conf  

    sqlSelect = get_bcbsa_value_based_pgms_df(config)  
    logger.info('sqlSelect df created.')  
    sqlSelect.persist().count()  

    s3_bucket_name = config.get('tgt_bucket_name')  

    logger.info("total records : {}".format(sqlSelect.count()))  
    folder_name = f'{CONTEXT_NAME}/{STRDATE}/'  
    s3_bucket_name = config.get('tgt_bucket_name')  
    s3_path = f's3://{s3_bucket_name}/{FOLDER_PATH}/'  

    logger.info(f'Writing to {s3_path} as csv')  

    sqlSelect \  
            .replace("", None) \  
            .coalesce(1) \  
            .write \  
            .mode('overwrite') \  
            .format('csv') \  
            .option("header", "false") \  
            .option("sep", "|") \  
            .option("quote", "") \  
            .option("escape", "") \  
            .option("nullValue", None) \  
            .save(s3_path)  

    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(s3_bucket_name)  

    file_number = 0  
    logger.info(f'Target path : {s3_bucket_name}/{TARGET_FILE}')  
    for obj in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=f'{FOLDER_PATH}'):  
        source_filename = (obj.key).split('/')[-1]  
        logger.info(f'Source file name: {source_filename}')  
        copy_source = {  
            'Bucket': s3_bucket_name,  
            'Key': obj.key  
        }  
        file_number += 1  
        s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, s3_bucket_name, TARGET_FILE + ".txt")  
        **zip_obj = s3.Object(bucket_name='s3_bucket_name', key='obj.key')  
        buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get().read())  

        z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)  
        for filename in z.namelist():  
            file_info = z.getinfo(filename)  
            s3.meta.client.upload_fileobj(  
                z.open(filename),  
                Bucket=s3_bucket_name,  
                Key=obj.key  
            )**  
        s3.Object(s3_bucket_name, obj.key).delete()
```

The part in bold is what I tried to do and was expecting a file with [FILE_NAME.txt.gz] in the desired S3 path.
But the error looks like this -
2023-04-28 12:56:43,414 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(73)): Error from     Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/glue_extract_job.py", line 213, in 
execute_script(environment=EXEC_ENVIRONMENT,logger=logger, isdebug=False)
File "/tmp/glue_extract_job.py", line 131, in execute_script
buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get().read())
File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in **call**
response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation:     Access Denied

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not a spark problem, but boto not having access to s3 `in execute_script buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get().read())....GetObject operation: Access Denied`

By the way, you can compress the csv to gzip with spark, just add `.option("compression", "gzip")` and you won't get to configure boto3 to zip the csv file.